# Using OGR2OGR with LIBKML?

Tags: gdal, kml, ogr2ogr

I am trying to figure out how to use GDAL (ogr2ogr) to export spatial data from SQLServer to KML. The standard KML driver works, but it is not very robust. LIBKML has so much promise (layers, styling, etc), but I cannot find any examples of how to make use of this added functionality.

For example, this works:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -f LIBKML z.kml "MSSQL:server=box;database=main;trusted_conneciton=yes;tables=dbo.z" -where "state='DE'"
```

It exports a POINT from my table. I would like to customize labels, icons (color, scale and image) and balloon text. I would also like to create folders/layers.

Ideally, I'd love to use columns like "icon_scale" and "layer_name" in my source tables to control this customization ...

Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have figured this much out ... my table (in the above example = dbo.z) needs a column named OGR_STYLE and contains something like this:

`SYMBOL(id:"http://www.example.com/icon.png",c:#ffff00ff,s:0.5)`  

This allow me to set the image, color and size. See http://www.gdal.org/ogr_feature_style.html for more info.  

I still haven't quite figured out how to set the LABEL and would love an example of something that works that sets both SYMBOL and LABEL while using OGR2OGR.

Comment: To [set label/name](http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html), you can append `-dsco NameField=<here comes the name of your column for label>`.